# How to capture key events on a simple div?

Tags: javascript, events, key

If we want to capture a key event on a textbox or a contenteditable div we can just use the "addEventListener" method with "keypress", "keyup" events.. but..

If i want to capture the "keyup" event on a simple div element without the "contenteditable" attribute? how can i do this?

Comment: give example of the html you wish to add an event listener to (and which element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tabindex` attribute, so the div it's focusable. Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/87p6r7w6/1/

The user should focus the div first, or you can do it using `.focus()`